# Rebinding the name `module` in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, require

I'd like to get Racket to evaluate the syntax of .kicad_mod files that are s-expression data of the form:

```
(module LED-10MM (layer F.Cu) (tedit 55BDE3C5)
  (descr "LED 10mm")
  ...)
```

[full file here](https://github.com/KiCad/LEDs.pretty/blob/71b8ff043d923624a1923d07fa60a3314064d909/LED-10MM.kicad_mod)

I want to be able to mix Racket and "kicad_mod" syntax so I am trying to redefine the `module` function. As a start I tried:

```
;kicad_mod.rkt

#lang racket
(provide
 (except-out (all-from-out racket) #%module-begin module)
 (rename-out [module-begin #%module-begin]))

(define kicad_module "you got me")

(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr ...)
  (#%module-begin
   (provide (rename-out [kicad_module module]))))
```

and what finally kind of worked (though not in drracket but with racket interpreter direct) on the loading side:

```
;main.rkt

#lang racket
(module kicad_mod "kicad_mod.rkt")
(require 'kicad_mod)
(println module)
; => "you got me"
```

But if I try any other way it fails:

#### 1.

```
;main.rkt

#lang racket
(require "kicad_mod.rkt")`
```

results in an error:

```
 main.rkt:3:9: module: bad syntax
      in: module
      context...:
       standard-module-name-resolver
```

#### 2.

```
;main.rkt

#lang s-exp "kicad_mod.rkt"
(println module)
```

results in no outputs on stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[soegaard put me on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373020/738768) even though it wasn't a full answer.

What I was doing didn't make much sense since I didn't understand the `#%module-begin` redefinition and in what context the the code was being called.

If you amend `kicad_mod.rkt` to include a quoted expr like soegaard suggests:

```
(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr ...)
  (#%module-begin
   (provide (rename-out [kicad_module module]))
   'expr ...))
```

and have:

```
;main.rkt
#lang s-exp "kicad_mod.rkt"
(println module)
```

You actually get an output of `'(println module)` on stdout.  So the `(provide (rename-out...` is being called in the context of the module using our new language, executed just before the expressions (if you remove the quote from `expr` like soegaard's initial suggestion).

What I really wanted was to re-define `module` before that, at the same time as I am re-defining `#%module-begin`:

```
;kicad_mod.rkt

#lang racket
(provide
 (except-out (all-from-out racket) #%module-begin module)
 (rename-out [module-begin #%module-begin])
 (rename-out [kicad_module module]))

(define kicad_module "you got me")

(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr ...)
  (#%module-begin
   expr ...))
```

Which will work correctly with the `main.rkt` using `#lang s-exp` above. You still need the `#%module-begin` binding, even though it doesn't do anything at this point if you want to use `#lang s-exp`. It will come in handy later anyway, I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I can't write code in the comments.

This looks odd - shouldn't the expression be in the output?

```
(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr ...)
  (#%module-begin
   (provide (rename-out [kicad_module module]))))
```

Perhaps

```
(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr ...)
  (#%module-begin
   (provide (rename-out [kicad_module module]))
   expr ...))
```

or

```
(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr ...)
  (#%module-begin
   (provide (rename-out [kicad_module module]))
   'expr ...))
```

?

Comment: Thanks! You put me on the right track with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37375722/738768